# Access HTML form submitted value from a different javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, user-input

EDIT: Rephrased the question so that it is less ambiguous.

I have two HTML files, x.html and y.html, and I have two javascript files, x.js and y.js. I have a form in x.html like so:

```
<form action="y.html">
<input type="text" value="Blank." />
<br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note that x.html and x.js work together, and y.html and y.js work together.
I want to access the value that a user submits into this form from y.js. How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to transfer data between two different pages? Are they on the same origin? Are they open at the same time or does one open the other?

Comment: What was the reason to word this in such an abstract way?

Comment: It doesn't seem abstract to me.. Yes I want to transfer data between two different pages; I want to use the data from the submit form on one page in a separate page (in the javascript file of a separate page). I don't understand why this is such a bad question... lol.

Comment: @Corecase please answer the other two questions - Are they on the same origin? Are they open at the same time (different windows) or does one open the other (in the same window i.e. destroying itself)?

Comment: so use a get and read the querystring

Comment: The usual way is some server-side scripting, although it's also possible with static HTML.

Comment: @Paul S. The submission will cause the second page to open. I'm not totally sure what you mean by same origin?

Comment: @Corecase okay. As you've not posted any code I'm going to assume the _HTML_ is submitting the `<form>` which has `action="y.html"`, so as epascarello said; simply set `method="GET"` and then you can read the _GET query_ in _y'_ using `window.location.search`

Comment: Thank you Paul. I'll go ahead and rephrase my question so that it is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to keep *String data* across page loads on the [**same origin**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

---

In *x'*, where `formElement` is a reference to the `<form>` and `textElement` is the `<input>` or `<textarea>` reference, set up an event handler using [`node.addEventListener(event_type, handler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for when the `<form>` is submitted

```
formElement.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('foobar', textElement.value);
});
```

In *y'* you can then access

```
var foobar = window.sessionStorage.getItem('foobar');
if (foobar === null) console.warn('nothing got set on x :(');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, below is the source of a.html, use get method to send the data to b.html, and after redirect, the data of the form will be available in the query string like `/b.html?ta=sfsdfsdfsdfs`

```
<form action="b.html" method="get">
    <textarea name="ta" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="subBtn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use any the query string, or GET parameters to do so.
In the form on page x you can use define method as GET and when this form is submitted it will be directed to an address which includes your variable and parameter passed by the user. Now in page y you can just use `window.location.search` value and use the variable.
Also, you can make use of cookies and do the same.

If possible describe your problem in more detail so that one could post a relevant solution.

Comment: If cookies are an option (in a _JavaScript_ sense), don't use cookies - use `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`

Comment: How do I store the value inside localStorage or sessionStorage in the html form if I were to use this method?